# MariaDB Galera change default port

Tags: port, replication, mariadb, galera

Is there any option to start root node for MariaDB Galera cluster on specific port (instead of default 4567)?

Comment: http://www.codership.com/wiki/doku.php?id=galera_parameters This link has all the parameters for galera and how to set them.

Comment: Thx I already found what i needed :)
It can be changed by setting port option in wsrep_node_address config (found at http://www.codership.com/wiki/doku.php?id=mysql_galera_configuration#wsrep_node_address)